# Can't Edit Keyboard Settings in System Preferences At All - Unresponsive to Clicks

Tags: keyboard, settings, system-settings

When I navigate to **System Preferences** ▶ **Keyboard** to change shortcuts, etc., none of the buttons are responsive. I can't seem to change anything in the keyboard settings. They're not grayed out or anything; they just don't do anything when I click them. However, when I navigate to other System Preference settings, I can change them e.g. Display settings. Does anybody know what might be going on here and how to fix it?

Note: I have a Macbook Pro 2019 with the most up-to-date OS software. I also have an Anne Pro 2 wireless keyboard connected via Bluetooth. Not sure if that's a part of the issue.

Comment: They're switched on, ie checked on the left? [They're not editable if they're not. I assume you figured that out already, but just to clarify] They should also go into Edit if you select one, then hit Enter or Return.

Comment: What do you mean switched on? I don't see any checkbox that indicates that they're on or off? Regardless, I can't click any of the buttons on the Keyboard settings screen anyway even if I did. The only button I can click is back.

Comment: Example - first line inactive, no editing; second active can be edited. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcu2l.png

Comment: I can't even get to the Shortcuts tab from the initial Keyboard tab. Literally can't click anything but the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have just been a driver or something that failed because when I restarted my computer, I was able to click any and all settings with my mouse in system preferences.